# Error reading MIME multipart body part when video upload size 30MB but the code works for 1 MB?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

When I performed video uploads in
1st Upload - 1MB worked fine
2nd Upload - 2MB worked fine
3rd Upload - 30MB worked fine

I think provider keeps value of 1st (1 MB) video data and showing same for (30 MB) data

when I upload 1st Time 30MB it failed with 
"Internal Server error " and show exception in XMLHttpRequest i.e 
"Error reading MIME multipart body part."

I have added **requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1048576000"** in web.config

Below is the server side code.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Upload")]
        public async Task<string> Upload()
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            byte[] file = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            var result = Convert.ToBase64String(file);

            ServiceReference1.SBIMFSERVICEClient sBIMFSERVICEClient = new ServiceReference1.SBIMFSERVICEClient();
            var results = sBIMFSERVICEClient.GetBase64String(result);

            provider = null;
            return result;
        }
```

And from client side I am generating Uint8Array and posting with Ajax.

Please help me out.

Comment: Your service is deployed on IIS or running in debug mode?

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález Running in a debug mode..